# How do I delete a temp directory on Windows after using gitpython?

Tags: python, windows, gitpython

I have the following Python function, which I am running on Windows 7:

```
def update():
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    git.Git().clone('my_repo', temp_dir)
    try:
        repo = git.Repo(temp_dir)
        repo.index.add('*')
        repo.index.commit('Empty commit')
    finally:
        from git.util import rmtree
        rmtree(temp_dir)
```

Unfortunately, on the rmtree line, I get:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\myaccount\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpdega8h\\.git\\objects\\pack\\pack-0ea07d13498ab92388dc33fbabaadf37511623c1.idx'
```

What should I be doing to remove the temp directory in Windows?

Comment: Looks like your git process is not finished when it hits `finally` clause..

Comment: Maybe not, but *I'm* finished with it. There doesn't seem to be any `close` method. And I've tried adding `time.sleep(10)` before the `rmtree`, to no effect.

Comment: Can you add `del repo` before rmtree to force object destruction?

Comment: Adding `del repo` doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

A [lot](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20label%3Atag.leaks%20) of [effort](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/508) has been spend to fix this behavior in *Windows*, where file-locking is the default behavior of the filesystem, but as explained in the [Limitations](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#leakage-of-system-resources):

> [GitPython] was written in a time where destructors (as implemented in
>   the `__del__`  method) still ran deterministically."
>
> In case you still want to use it in such a context, you will want to search 
>   the codebase for `__del__` implementations and call these yourself when you see fit.

In any case, [this the trick](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/ce5dfe7f95ac35263e41017c8a3c3c40c4333de3/git/test/lib/helper.py#L147-L154) employed by the test-cases of the project may help:

```
repo_dir = tempfile.mktemp()
repo = Repo.init(repo_dir)
try:
    ## use the repo

finally:
    repo.git.clear_cache()    # kill deamon-procs responding to hashes with objects
    repo = None
    if repo_dir is not None:
        gc.collect()
        gitdb.util.mman.collect()  # kept open over git-object files
        gc.collect()
        rmtree(repo_dir)
```

> NOTE: this is what `repo.close()` does since 2.1.1 (Dec 2016).